# Lambda reference to a field

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'd like to know how to get lambda reference to a field.
I don't want to use a method because my field is public final.
I suspect this is impossible but I don't see an obvious statement.

```
class A {
   public final String id;
   ...
}

Map<String, A> f(List<A> l) {
   return l.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(A::id, Function.identity()));
}
```

Comment: `a -> a.id`. Why are you using public fields in the first place?

Comment: @JBNizet, I like public final fields in classes which are data structures. They don't implement interfaces or have deep hierarchies.

Comment: Wy do you want a lambda reference? You can always use an instance to access `public` fields. Like `new A().id`. And I hope you have a really `STRONG` reason to create a public field. But since it is `final`, I don't think thats gonna create a problem.

Comment: @Aditya, I want a reference because it's shorter.

Comment: @JBNizet, OOAD is not the absolute truth. I like to apply tools where they are appropriate. Getters of immutable fields often just waste of lines and time.

Comment: Can't you just use your IDE to autogenerate some GETTER methods for your fields to use as "references"?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can always use a lambda expression:

```
return l.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a.id, Function.identity()));
```

I think that "method references" are called this way for a reason, and therefore apply only for methods.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that for real life scenarios, `x->x.id` is shorter than `ClassName::id`. Only for sample code using class names consisting two chars or less it might look different.

Comment: @Holger true, but shorter code is not always what people are looking for. If it was, we'll all be naming our classes and variables a,b,c,d,... :). Some people may prefer the method references syntax over lambda expressions.

Comment: it’s not always what people are looking for but in this specific case [the OP said himself “I want a reference because it's shorter”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467946/java8-lambda-reference-to-a-field/27467956?noredirect=1#comment43374811_27467946)

Comment: Does anyone notice that for every `->` a new method is generated? We should prefer the method reference syntax when possible. It's sad there's none for fields.

Answer (score 58):

It sounds like you're hoping that Java has a corresponding feature for *field references* as it does for *method references*.  But this is not the case.  Method references are shorthand for a certain category of lambda expressions, but there is no corresponding syntax for fields.  Field literals were explored during the JSR-335 Expert Group deliberation (there is some reference to it here http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2011-November/004235.html) but were not included in Java SE 8.