# Java stream API: map field without getter syntax

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

```
class Person {
    public String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
}
```

Are there special syntax sugar for accessing fields in stream API through lambda? I see:

```
List<Person> persons;
persons.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
persons.stream().map(p -> p.name).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What about something like (which is not working, I know that):

```
persons.stream().map(Person::name).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Java8 lambda reference to a field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467946/java8-lambda-reference-to-a-field)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no method-reference-like syntax for field access. Sometimes that would have been convenient.

#### Motivation

The fact that there isn't has some justification in that it's a bit strange in Java to regard fields as methods. It would also create difficulties with overloading since a field and a method can have the same name.

#### Work-around

Provide a getter for the field as in the example in the question text. Or use a lambda expression instead. Something like this:

```
someMethod(obj -> obj.someField);
```

Comment: What would that lambda expression be?

Comment: @KeithTyler: I added an example to the answer text.