# How to get a field reference in java?

Tags: java, reflection, reference, field

i am trying to get a compile time safe field reference in java, done not with reflection and Strings, but directly referencing the field. Something like

`MyClass::myField`

I have tried the usual reflection way, but you need to reference the fields as strings, and this is error prone in case of a rename, and will not throw a compile time error

EDIT: just want to clarify that my end goal is to get the field NAME for entity purposes, such as reference the entity field in a query, and not the value

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do. The method reference syntax only works for methods, but anything you can do with a method reference, you can (more or less) do with the lambda syntax.

Comment: @shmosel i am trying to get a compile-time safe **field** reference the same way a method reference works

Comment: Not sure that’s going to be feasible without naming your getter accordingly.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? That is, how would you like to use the reference?

Comment: Java doesn't have a corresponding feature for [field references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27472025/636009) as it does for method references. There was a thread on the [Amber Spec Observers](https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/amber-spec-observers/) mailing list in June of 2019 on [Revisiting field references](https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/amber-spec-observers/2019-June/001504.html) but it didn't go anywhere.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do with it, it might be enough to take method references to the getter (and, if there is one, setter) for the field.

Comment: @tgdavies Basically im creating queries which need the JPA entity property name as string, and every time i want to change a property i need to also change every string reference. I was hoping there was a way to do MyClass::myField so that if i change it, all these referenced will not compile

Comment: Please give more details of what you were hoping to do. Do you mean something like `entityManger.createQuery("select x from MyEntity x where x." + MyEntity::name + " = :entityName")`?

Comment: @tgdavies exactly. Currently i do "where x.name", but every time i change any field i have to find tens of those references

Comment: For what it's worth, Intellij IDEA has good support for refactoring field names of entities, if the entity and the query are in the same project.

Comment: Or look at generating metamodel classes: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjiup.html

Comment: Why does the query depend on the field name? And why do you change field names so often that it matters?

Comment: How could it possibly not depend in the field name?

Comment: A good framework would use the public methods that make up the API of a class rather than accessing private fields but what is the entity manager processing anyway? Your field or a database column? Maybe you’re just using the wrong framework?

Comment: It's common in almost all ORM to do queries with the object field, the name of which is mapped to the column

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, you might as well want to wish for a unicorn. The notion of 'a field reference', in the sense that you are asking for, simply isn't part of java-the-language.

That `MyClass::myThing` syntax works *only* for methods. There's simply no such thing for fields. It's unfortunate.

It's very difficult to give objective reasons for the design decisions of any language; it either requires spelunking through the designer's collective heads which requires magic or science fiction, or asking them to spill the beans, which they're probably not going to do in a stack overflow question. Sometimes (and more recent java features, such as this one), design is debated in public. Specifically, you can search for the openjdk `lamba-dev` mailing list where no doubt this question was covered. You'll need to go through, and I'm not exaggerating, tens of thousands of posts, but, the good news is, [it's searchable](https://mail.openjdk.org/pipermail/lambda-dev/).

But, I can guess / dig through my own memory as I spent some time discussing Project Lambda as it was designed:

Direct field access isn't common in the java ecosystem. The language *allows* direct field access but few java programs are written that way, so why make a language feature that would only be immediately useful and familiar to an exotic bunch.

The infrastructure required is also rather significant - a method lambda isn't allowed to be written in java **unless** you use it in a context that makes it possible for the compiler to 'treat' the lambda as a type - specifically, a `@FunctionalInterface` - any interface that contains exactly 1 method (other than methods that already exist in j.l.Object itself). In other words, this is fine:

```
Function<String, String> f = String::toLowerCase;
```

But this is not:

```
Object o = String::toLowerCase;
```

So, let's imagine for a moment that field refs did exist. What does that mean? What is the 'type' of the expression `MyClass::myField`? Perhaps a new concept: An interface with **2** methods; one of them takes no arguments and returns a T, the other wants a T and returns nothing (to match the act of reading the field, and writing it), but where it's also acceptable if it's a FunctionalInterface that is either one of those, perhaps? That sounds complicated.

The general mindset of the java design team right now (and has been for a while) is not to overcomplicate matters: Do not add features unless you have a good reason. After all, if it turns out that the community really clamours for field refs, they can be added. But, if on the other hand, they were added but nobody uses them, they can't be removed (and thus you've now permanently made the language more complicated and reduced room for future language features for a thing nobody uses and which most style guides tell you to actively avoid).

That's, I'm pretty sure, why they don't exist.

Comment: I would imagine that MyClass::myField would return a Field object the same way you get once by using reflection. All i want is to get the reference at compile time, and use the field name in queries, to be sure it is always correct, rather than expect it to break at runtime with a 'field "myField" not found'

Comment: @dac1n But that's not what these references are about at all. `Method m = MyClass::myMethod` isn't legal java either.

Comment: Project Lombok gives a few outs for this, notably, [`FieldNameConstants`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/FieldNameConstants). (DISCLAIMER: I'm a core maintainer of Lombok).

Comment: wow thanks this is probably what i need. Will take a look